# QMenuBar reimplementing MousePressEvent

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a window with FramelessWindowHint.
I also have a QMenuBar attached to the QMainWindow.
I want to grab mouse press events when the user clicks the menubar. I thought I could make a new class like so:

```
class menubarclass(QtWidgets.QMenuBar):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
```

Then reimplement the mousePressEvent function in that class.

```
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("menubar clicked")
```

The problem is that reimplementing this function seems to override the functionality of menus/actions in the menubar - I can't click them.

So I'm thinking I need to decorate the mousePressEvent rather than reimplement it, but I'm not sure how to do it, because this is an event handler.

In short, I don't want to override the mousePressEvent handler, but add additional code to it, if that makes sense?

Comment: If you just call the base implementation (`super().mousePressEvent(event)`) within your implementation, it should work. If it doesn't, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can understand what's going on.

Comment: That has worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Musicamante provided me with the answer I needed

> If you just call the base implementation (super().mousePressEvent(event)) within your implementation, it should work. If it doesn't, please provide a minimal, reproducible example so that we can understand what's going on.